# Unable to reach services via Azure Traffic Manager and Nginx Ingress on AKS

Tags: azure, nginx, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, azure-traffic-manager

I have two AKS clusters as primary and secondary in two different regions.
I want to use Azure traffic manager for the the Priority based endpoint monitoring and fail-over mechanism on the primary and secondary clusters.
I got two services: A and B that routes at the relative path */service-a* and */service-b* respectively. I have nginx ingress controller on each cluster with PIP mapped to the custom host *aks-primary.xyz.com* and *aks-secondary.xyz.com* respectively.

The services are reachable on the below paths:

On Primary Custer:

https://aks-primary.xyz.com/service-a

https://aks-primary.xyz.com/service-b

On secondary cluster:

https://aks-secondary.xyz.com/service-a

https://aks-secondary.xyz.com/service-b

I added the primary and secondary host *aks-primary.xyz.com* and *aks-secondary.xyz.com* as the endpoint in the Azure Traffic Manager for priority based routing. I added the probe path */healthz* and port 443.
My endpoints are online.

I added the custom domain for the ATM FQDN my-atm.trafficmanager.net to aks.xyz.com
I am unable to reach to my services on below paths

https://aks.xyz.com/service-a

https://aks.xyz.com/service-b

Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

I got this resolved.

I added the ingress with two hosts on each cluster.

hosts: *aks-primary.xyz.com* and *aks.xyz.com* on cluster aks primary.

hosts: *aks-secondary.xyz.com* and *aks.xyz.com* on cluster aks secondary.

A sample ingress on cluster aks primary:

```sh
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-with-atm
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
  - host: aks-primary.xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service-a
          servicePort: 80
        path: /service-a
      - backend:
          serviceName: service-b
          servicePort: 80
        path: /service-b
  - host: aks.xyz.com
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: service-a
          servicePort: 80
        path: /service-a
      - backend:
          serviceName: service-b
          servicePort: 80
        path: /service-b
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - aks-primary.xyz.com
    secretName: tls-secret-wildcard-for-xyz-com
  - hosts:
    - aks.xyz.com
    secretName: tls-secret-wildcard-for-xyz-com`
```

Cheers!

Comment: Did you add the NGINX Ingress Controllers Public IP of each cluster as the endpoints in Azure TM or else the FQDN?